# 2-step verification on Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account, multi-factor-auth

I recently heard from my friend that Gmail is showing that I have activated 2-set verification in their Gmail account, like a promotion or something.

- Is Gmail doing this?
- Is it possible that Gmail would do something like that?

I will give an example: I am `xyz@gmail.com` and I have activated 2-step verification. I have `abc@gmail.com` as one of my contacts.

Would Gmail show in `abc@gmail.com` account that `xyz@gmail.com` has activated 2-step verification?

Provided:

1. `xyz@gmail.com` is also in `abc@gmail.com`'s contact list;
2. `xyz@gmail.com` is not in `abc@gmail.com`'s contact list.

Comment: do you mean Multifactor authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if you have it activated by logging in to the [dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/b/0/?pli=1) and going to [`Account - manage account - security - 2 step verification`](https://www.google.com/settings/) and see if it is `on` or `off`

As you agree to their [privacy policy](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/) it is entirely feasible that they would use that information about you to promote one of their products to a contact of yours, or someone that has you listed as a contact. Remember, they are in the business of selling.

Answer (score 0):

Google have introduced a second layer of security to avoid people hi-jacking your account. See their [BLOG](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/advanced-sign-in-security-for-your.html) for detailed explanation.
As far as I know it is only turned on when you ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

> Would gmail show in abc@gmail.com account, that xyz@gmail.com has activated 2-step verification? Provided :

No. Only accounts which you use & are authorized to check are shown if Two-factor auth is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

I use multifactor authentication with multiple Google accounts currently. To my understanding, ONLY if:

- `abc@gmail.com` has `xyz@gmail.com`'s password will `abc@gmail.com` be able to see the second page with the mulitfactor auth prompt
- `xyz@gmail.com` tells `abc@gmail.com` that he isusing Multifactor Auth

Will `abc@gmail.com` be able to tell `xyz@gmail.com` is using Multifactor authentication.

Edit:
I just remembered one more way that `abc@gmail.com` would beable to know if `xyz@gmail.com` is using multifactor auth: If `abc@myowngmail.com` is a Google Apps administrator for `@myowngmail.com`, `abc@myowngmail.com` will be able to know wether `@myowngmail.com` is enabled to let users to enable multifactor on accounts under `@myowngmail.com`.